# Is Polymer v1.0 compatible with phonegap build?

Tags: polymer, phonegap-build, polymer-1.0

Is Polymer v1.0 compatible with phonegap build?  I tried to build the polymer starter kit but the build was not a success.

Comment: If you make clear to the reader what question you are asking that will improve your chances of getting a useful reply.  Reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might give you some ideas.  Ideally you should post a small test case and the specific errors you are seeing as described in [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ahemed,
Polymer is new and experimental. It works with only a few browsers. Phonegap, at this time, does NOT support polymer. Your questions are best directed to the one and only (as of the moment) meetup group in Silicon Valley on this subject.
http://www.meetup.com/Web-Components-Silicon-Valley-Meetup/ 
Best of Luck.