# Is there a working Polymer StarterKit 1.0 and Phone Gap / Cordova android build?

Tags: cordova, polymer, polymer-starter-kit, firebase-polymer

I am having issues with building my Polymer 1.0 app through PhoneGap. When I use phonegap to build the android apk and install it on my phone it shows the index.html file from the bower_components. Whichever element has the first index.html is what I see on my phone when the app runs.

I have been successful in building android apk with polymer .5 but not 1.0.

Is there a successful build of the Polymer 1.0 StarterKit android apk?

Is anyone else having issues with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31688434/1640892) suggests that PhoneGap Build did not support Polymer as of July 28, 2015.

Also, [they provided this link](http://www.meetup.com/Web-Components-Silicon-Valley-Meetup/) to a group possibly working on it.